# Can I overload a function based on class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that will behave differently based on class of its argument, for instance:

```
equal :: a -> a -> True
```

will return `(==)` if `a` is instance of `Eq` and `False` otherwise. Is it possible?

Comment: No. You can never check for negatives like "if T is **not** in class C then ...". This is because an instance could be defined anywhere, so the compiler would need to explore _all_ the modules in the program to ensure the _absence_ of an instance. This is inefficient, and breaks separate compilation.

Comment: What you can of course do is define your own class whose instances implement different behaviour for different types.

Comment: I will tell you about [*if-instance*](https://github.com/sheaf/if-instance), and I won't tell you if it's the wrong tool: `ifSat @Eq (==) \_ _ -> False`